# JSON doesnt post data

Tags: jquery, json

I have a question about json. First I made this jquery code±

```
    <script>
        $('#buy').click(function(){
        var items=[]; 
            var item={
                    firstname:'blabla'                  
                };
                items.push(item);           
                var sortorder={ items: items };
           $.post('post_form.php', 'data='+$.toJSON(sortorder)+'', function(response){      
              alert(response);          
           });                  
    });
   </script>
```

If you can see the data will be send to post_form.php but doesn't reach it I think, this the code:

```
 if(!$_POST["data"]){
    echo "Invalid data";
    exit;
}   
include('config.php');
$data=json_decode($_POST["data"]);

foreach($data->items as $item)   
{  
    $query = "insert into customer (id,firstname) VALUES ('','".mysql_escape_string($item->firstname)."')";
     mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
     echo 'succes';
}
 echo 'fail';
```

Everytime I get the fail echo very strange, I used it for another script and worked very well.
This script doesn't receive the data info, how to fix?

Regards and thanks,

Frank

Comment: What happens when you echo $_POST["data"]?

Comment: I will recieve this "fail {\"items\":[{\"firstname\":\"blabla\"}]}",hmm strange slashes "\". Btw, I get this error message in firebug: "uncaught exception cannot modify properties of a wrappednative", ah wtf.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use

```
   $.post('post_form.php', { "data" : $.toJSON(sortorder) }, function(response){      
      alert(response);          
   });
```

post variables will be escaped in this way

Comment: http://www.jiro-optiek.nl/ add a sunglass by click on "kopen" (dutch for buy), fill in your information it's very strange never had this before.